# how to access an value in the nested list ,without using indexes and slicing?

Tags: python

```
l=[1,3,4,[100,10],4,5,,,,]
```

I want to print the sublist [100,10] or access the values in it in a list of million values , using list comprehension or lambda or any other , how to achieve this

In Simple

i want to identify the sublist or an item in the sublist in a list (which has millions of values) with out using slicing or indexing

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you're asking for. Are you asking to find the nested list? `next(x for x in l if isinstance(x, list))` Are you asking to print out the values in the list? Could there be multiple lists? Are you searching for a specific value in the sublist? Why can't you use "indexes and slicing"? Please edit your question to include more details.

Comment: i want to identify the sublist or an item in the sublist  in a list (which has millions of values)  with out using slicing or indexing

Comment: Why dont you use a for loop to iterate through the elements of the main list. Check for the type of the element and if it is a list iterate through the sublist to fetch the values in the sublist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to just find all sub-lists you can do:

```
my_sublists = [n for n in my_list if isinstance(n,list)]
```

or

```
for n in my_list:
    if isinstance(n,list):
        do_whatever_you_want_to_do_with_sublist(n)
```